# Using JSON to get Javascript code from another domain

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having some trouble getting JSON to store some Javascript as a string value.

```
{
"code": "function test(){alert('coreg.js has been loaded'); if (jQuery) { alert('We have jQuery!'); } else { alert('We don\'t have jQuery...'); } }"
}
```

When I validate this using [www.jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com) it says I've got a syntax error (unexpected TINVALID at line 2) but I can't for the life of me see what it is. The Javascript is all entirely valid, all I did was take my function and put double quotes outside it.

I'm really confused! Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the escape: **`We don\\'t have jQuery`**

```
{
"code": "function test(){alert('coreg.js has been loaded'); if (jQuery) { alert('We have jQuery!'); } else { alert('We don\\'t have jQuery...'); } }"
}
```

though if you are using json to get JS code from another domain, you wont be able to do it unless the other domain supports JSONP, or you are using grease monkey's XHR

Comment: Yeah, I realised it didn't like the backslash but forgot about double-escaping... stupid mistake :P Thanks! (and yeah, I'm using JSONP)